# how many threads do scala's parallel collections use by default?

Tags: multithreading, scala, parallel-processing

When I call `Array.tabulate(100)(i=>i).par map { _+ 1}`, how many threads are being used?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming there are no concurrently running processes and/or threads, meaning that all the CPU and cores are idle, this will be 1 thread per logical processor on the CPU. For example, if you have an Intel processor with 4 cores, but those cores have hyperthreading, then there will be 8 worker threads executing the parallel operation..

In any case, this is the same value returned by the [`availableProcessors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors%28%29) method in the JDK.

Be aware that the `tabulate` call in your example is not parallel - it is executed sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

For par map on Arrays scala is using it's custom ForkJoinThreadPool default implementation, which uses the number of detected processors from the java runtime. You can see it [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/forkjoin/scala/concurrent/forkjoin/ForkJoinPool.java#L2820):

```
 public ForkJoinPool() {
        this(Math.min(MAX_CAP, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()),
             defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, null, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to a comment on [this](http://beust.com/weblog/2011/08/15/scalas-parallel-collections/) post, the default is 1 thread per core.